# ajax options.complete v/s load callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a script in which I add a options.complete handler for each Ajax call triggered using jQuery.
   Which works well for all ajax calls except the one where 
   load() is used with a callback as 3rd parameter.

In such scenario if options.complete and load callback both are provided then
   load callback are never triggered. Anyone knows whats the issue here

Is the options.complete is same as load callback handler ?

After downloading JQuery -

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.startTime = new Date().getTime();
    options.complete = function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        var timeTaken = new Date().getTime() - jqXHR.startTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code snippet ?

Comment: After downloading JQuery - 
    jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
     jqXHR.startTime = new Date().getTime();
     options.complete = function(jqXHR, textStatus){
      var timeTaken = new Date().getTime() - jqXHR.startTime;
     }
}  This way I can use options.complete().    But when Ajax calls are triggered using load() with callback.. then callback handlers are not getting executed. Why?

Comment: basically `load()` function in jquery used for loading external resources, it may be some link or any webpage. I mean fetch data from the server. `ajaxPrefilter` basically used for filter your request before they are sending to `$.ajax()` (if I am not wrong).. I am still not clear with your question.. sorry

Comment: My goal is to startTime before any ajax call is sent and get the endTime once ajax call completed.
I want to achieve this by adding a global handler. (Do not want every single ajax call to do this by themself)
1.  jQuery.ajaxPrefilter - Helps me get startTime
2.  options.complete     - Helps me get endTime
This whole process works fine if AJAX calls are triggered using $.ajax()


But there is a .load(url, data, callback) which can also be used for making AJAX calls
When .load() is used with a callback, the above given implementation fails
callback never gets executed, why is the question here